# Updating datefield from a string with UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, date, datetime, cursor

I have a string I'm slicing and then using UpdateCursor to update rows with the outputs. The string is formatted like this:

Foo_YYYYmmddHM_Xy_Ab_Bar

I'm struggling in getting only the YYYYmmdd part of the string in a date field. My current approach is:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dataset, ["String", "Year_short","Date_date"]) as updateRows:
    for row in updateRows:
        string_split = row[0].split("_")
        row[1] = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_split[1], '%Y%m%d%H%M').year 
        row[2] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(string_split[1], '%Y%m%d%H%M')).strftime("%Y%m%d")
        updateRows.updateRow(row)
```

row[1] updates OK because the field is a short type, however no matter what I've tried row[2] will fail unless I include the HM component part of the date. Above is my last attempt but I have also tried the following with no success:

```
   row[2] = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_split[1], '%Y%m%d%H%M').date
   row[2] = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_split[1], '%Y%m%d%)
```

Comment: You could try using the datetime constructor datetime.datetime(Year, Month, Day) with int from a sliced string: **datetime.datetime(int(string_split[1][:4]),int(string_split[1][4:6]),int(string_split[1][-2:]))** provided you are *absolutely sure* that the dates are 8 characters in YYYYmmdd format.

Comment: @MichaelStimson that worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: That's good news. Can you please answer your own question with a snippet of your working code for future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked a treat, thanks to Michael Stimson:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dataset, ["String", "Year_short","Date_date"]) as updateRows:
    for row in updateRows:
        string_split = row[0].split("_")
        row[1] = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_split[1], '%Y%m%d%H%M').year 
        row[2] = datetime.datetime(int(string_split[1][:4]),int(string_split[1][4:6]),int(string_split[1][-2:]))
```

Output was as expected - YYYYmmdd